# Simulating Data Readings from the Some Electronics Device? Which Language to choose?

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls

In Our QC Department, we are using some kind of QC equipment which take transformers Parameter reading . and we have to take 12  different parameters values each time for ever 200 - 300  different conditions .

Each reading should be noted and should me printed and given to the buyer of the transformers.  so it is time consuming and device cost is also huge to do the Physical Quality check of the Transformers.

So our QC technical dept asked IT Service team to develop an application which generate Random readings for the given parameters.

Totally 12  parameters are there

On their experience, they figured out the The Value range for each 12  parameters ( Max and Min values of the reading .

and they will give max and min value for all 12  parameters  .. so our application should generate random sequence of 12 parameters whose values should with in the max and min values. and we need to get 200 - 300  set of readings.   how to start this project? which language will handle this kind of calculation .. we are familiar with the C# to some extent   .. we are ready to  share further information,  if required?

Comment: Ehh... Am I right in reading that you want to generate random data _instead_ of doing the actual measurements?

Comment: @HenkHolterman   .. correct ... and to make cost cutting and time saving this necessary and any ow we will test the random reading in physical test for say 3-5  reading of the generated result then doing for all 200 times..

Comment: @HenkHolterman , you are mistaken our problem here .. we need to manually give 200  times 12  different values i.e 200 times with 12 different values for each other parameters. in once case we need to chnage parameters in increment of 0.01 .. so it is hard to do some paper work to do this hectic listing of values ..

Comment: @HenkHolterman  if we achieve the result using software then we can take print out and allot to our employyes to carry out cross check  the values using the physical instrument and more ever calculation in the coding will be done accrediting to Scientific Formula used to calculate the parameter. As we get Different kind of Transformers to manufacture so its take hard to prepare values manually to test the instrument

Comment: @HenkHolterman  we are only trying reduce our Manual procedure of caluclating parameters and its possiblities and this things can be done by Noting down random values by hand also .. any how Final QC test will be done on the result we got forma the software.

Comment: so... define the min/max of each parameter, and randomize the values in them? Heck, create a simple class with those 12 parameters/properties. create an method that randomly fills those values based on their min/max values and voila. Go eat pizza and cake. Drink some beer and call it a day. you might have a bit of extra logic depending on the fields but hey. That's what they pay you for.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the language you most familiar with, or is used widely in your organization. No matter what. Considering that you tagged a `C#`, choose it like a principal language.

First I would define a `API` for generating arbitrary inputs and simulating device responce, let's call it `simulator`. As after that, having kind of `SDK` for that purpose you can use it whenever you want:

- Command line app
- Windows Forms
- WPF
- APS.NET
- Web Service

In other way, the *interface* is matter of commodity or company strategy choice, so decouple yourself form it, like it *could* be a subject to change.

Comment: I see you're only trying to help (a complete newbie) so a +1 from me. The downvote was probably from someone who doesn't think SO is a place for "How do I (a.k.a could you) write my application"

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson: infact, I didn't write a single line of the code here, but give my opinion on direction OP should look at, imo. I'm perfectly aware that here people prefer have a coding, concrete q/a, but don't share it, as sometimes, what we need is just a direction or technology to look at and the rest could be found from sites like this, books, collegues and cetra.

Comment: imagine if someone registered as @downvoter, they'd get all these nasty messages, lol. ps I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is Computer Automation.
Get the specifications for these measurements, identify the test equipment needed.
The develop a WPF application which will interface to the test equipment. 
Identify the test equipment with a suitable H/W interface (USB, IEEE-488, etc.).
Create a detailed design for the S/W & H/W. Document design plan, budget, schedule, milestones, etc. Present your proposal to management.

"So our QC technical dept asked IT Service team to develop an application which generate Random readings for the given parameters."
QC's plan, as you described it, is NOT a plan.